Edge coloring in Arc Diagram
I have a dataframe with 3 columns and I create an arc diagram  ( source x target).
I don't know how to colour my edge with st_disease.
Here is my code :
links <- data.frame(
source = c("Convalescent plasma", "Convalescent whole blood", "Gentamicin", "Interferon β-1a", "Lopinavir/ritonavir and recombinant IFN-β1b", "MAb114", "Plasma", "Plasma", "REGN-EB3", "Remdesivir", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Tecovirimat", "ZMapp"),
target = c("No active treatment", "No active treatment", "Doxycycline", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "ZMapp", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "ZMapp", "ZMapp", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "Favipiravir"),
st_disease = c("Ebola", "Ebola", "Plague", "Ebola", "MERS", "Ebola", "Lassa fever", "Lassa fever", "Ebola", "Ebola", "Nipah", "Crimean Congo Haemorrhagic Fever", "Crimean Congo Haemorrhagic Fever", "Lassa fever", "Lassa fever", "Lassa fever", "Mpox", "Ebola")
)
mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(links)
p2 <-  ggraph(mygraph, layout="linear") +
geom_edge_arc0(edge_colour="#69b3a2",
edge_alpha=0.3,
edge_width=1.5) +
geom_node_point( color="#69b3a2", size=5, position = "identity") +
geom_node_text( aes(label=name), repel = TRUE, size=4, color="black", nudge_y=-0.5 ,angle=70, vjust=1) +
scale_edge_color_manual(values = col)+
theme_void() +
theme(
legend.position="none",
# plot.margin=unit(rep(2,4), "cm")
plot.margin=unit(c(4,2,2,2), "cm"))+
coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
p2
I tried to change edge_colour but I dot not understand why it's asking a Aesthetics of length 72.

Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help your, if your provide the code which results in an error. Have you mapped on aesthetics, i.e. have you used geom_edge_arc0(aes(color = st_disease), edge_alpha=0.3, edge_width=1.5) or have you used something like edge_colour = links$st_disease outside of aes() (which will result in an error)?

Sorry I let some row in comments in my code , I tried  geom_edge_arc0(aes(color = st_disease) the error message is Error in geom_edge_arc0():
! Problem while setting up geom aesthetics.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in check_aesthetics():
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as
the data (72).
✖ Fix the following mappings: edge_colour

I also tried edge_colour = links$st_disease outside of aes() same error message

I am not sure what the scale_edge_color_manual(values = col) in your code is supposed  to be. Assuming it is a vector defining the color palette , I do not see it defined. You can create the color palette first and then use scale_edge_color_manual to use that palette for your plot.
library(ggraph)


links <- data.frame(
  source = c("Convalescent plasma", "Convalescent whole blood", "Gentamicin", "Interferon β-1a", 
             "Lopinavir/ritonavir and recombinant IFN-β1b", "MAb114", "Plasma", "Plasma", "REGN-EB3", 
             "Remdesivir", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", "Ribavirin", 
             "Tecovirimat", "ZMapp"), 
  target = c("No active treatment", "No active treatment", "Doxycycline", "No active treatment", 
             "No active treatment", "ZMapp", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "ZMapp", 
             "ZMapp", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", 
             "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", "No active treatment", 
             "Favipiravir"), 
  st_disease = c("Ebola", "Ebola", "Plague", "Ebola", "MERS", "Ebola", "Lassa fever", "Lassa fever", 
                 "Ebola", "Ebola", "Nipah", "Crimean Congo Haemorrhagic Fever", 
                 "Crimean Congo Haemorrhagic Fever", "Lassa fever", "Lassa fever", "Lassa fever", 
                 "Mpox", "Ebola")
)

mygraph <- graph_from_data_frame(links)

# Create a color palette for the st_disease column
disease_colors <- setNames(
  c("#e41a1c", "#377eb8", "#4daf4a", "#984ea3", "#ff7f00", "#ffff33", "#a65628", "#f781bf"),
  unique(links$st_disease)
)


p2 <- ggraph(mygraph, layout = "linear") +
  geom_edge_arc(aes(edge_colour = st_disease), edge_width = 1.5, edge_alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_node_point(color = "#69b3a2", size = 5) +
  geom_node_text(aes(label = name), repel = TRUE, size = 4, color = "black", 
                 nudge_y = -0.5, angle = 70, vjust = 1) +
  scale_edge_color_manual(values = disease_colors) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "right", plot.margin = unit(c(4, 2, 2, 2), "cm")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

p2


Glad to hear. If you are satisfied with the answer kindly mark it as the accepted answer (the green tick will appear).
